# Configuring Nginx with Unicorn Flask within Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm having an issue configuring my nginx.conf for the **container (server)** container.

- **Without nginx**: I can properly access the app through gunicorn.
- **With nginx**: I get 502 Bad Gateway

[image]

My first question would be, should I even have nginx on the container(server) if I have ingress nginx?

My second question is, why is this configuration not working. Here is my docker file for container (server)

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3 as builder
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT [ "gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000", "run:app" ]

FROM nginx
EXPOSE 80
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

`nginx.conf`

```
upstream flask_server {
    server localhost:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://flask_server;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

`Command`

```
# build
docker build -t test/server .
# run
docker run -p 80:80 test/server
```

I suppose my issue is the upstream localhost is not working. When I'm developing locally is there no way for me to test this container specifically through docker? Or do I have to test locally with docker-compose and put nginx in a separate container?

Answer (score 0):

I know, that post could be outdated, but it is still searching by Google :)

> #### My second question is, why is this configuration not working. Here is my docker file for container (server)

So, as I can see, your specified `proxy_pass` as `http://flask_server`.
That means, `flask_server` hostname should be the resolvable name.

- This name could be just the name of your Docker container, but your Dockerfile or `docker run` does not contain such options.
- This name could be group of servers, but in this case, you have to define this directive

```
upstream flask_server {
    server <hostname1>;
    server <hostname2>;
}
```

(c) https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

> If a domain name resolves to several addresses, all of them will be used in a round-robin fashion. In addition, an address can be specified as a [server group](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html).

To sum up: to fix 502 error (which means connection timeout to the upstream) you can use 2 ways:

- change `proxy_pass http://flask_server;` to `proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;`
  OR
- define `upstream` directive according [manual](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html)

> #### My first question would be, should I even have nginx on the container(server) if I have ingress nginx?

In my opinion - I should not.
You can deploy Nginx on the container(server) just in case you want (in the future) load-balance traffic between multiply gunicorn instances or want to provide some HTTP authentication or access restrictions.